# Capistrano assets:precompile fails deployment and the logs are unclear, can someone else take a look?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, rbenv, capistrano3

I've been at this for about 16 hours and throwing in the towel. I've successfully deployed an rails app with capistrano before and I copied everything initially, but I can't get past assets:precompile. Migration doesn't work either, but one thing at the time.

```
Capfile

# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"
# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
require "capistrano/rbenv"
#require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails"
#require "capistrano/rails/assets"
#require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require 'capistrano/puma'

install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Nginx

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

```
config/deploy.rb
set :application,   'livelyteams'
set :repo_url,      'https://github.com/unusualslim/livelyteams'
set :puma_threads,  [4,16]
set :puma_workers,  0
set :rbenv_ruby,    '2.6.5'
set :rails_env,         'production'

append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

# append :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/home/dev/apps/livelyteams'

set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, File.read('.ruby-version').strip
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"

set :default_env, {
   PATH: '$HOME/.npm-packages/bin/:$PATH',
   NODE_ENVIRONMENT: 'production'
}

# Default value for :scm is :git
# set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:yarn_install"

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Run rake yarn:install'
  task :yarn_install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute("cd #{release_path} && yarn install")
      end
    end
  end
end  

namespace :deploy do
  namespace :check do
    before :linked_files, :set_master_key do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 10 do
        unless test("[ -f #{shared_path}/config/master.key ]")
          upload! 'config/master.key', "#{shared_path}/config/master.key"
        end
      end
    end
  end


end



namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "#{fetch(:rbenv_prefix)} pumactl -P ~/app/current/tmp/pids/puma.pid phased-restart"
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

```
config/deploy/production.rb

set :stage, :production
set :branch, "master"

server 'livelyteams.com', user: "dev", port: 22, roles: %w{app db web}, primary: true
```

I think it's related to RAILS_ENV=production, but I've tried everything I could think of.

and the capistrano.log

```
 DEBUG [b2a3647b] Command: cd /home/dev/apps/livelyteams/releases/20200918213106 && yarn install
 DEBUG [b2a3647b]   yarn install v1.21.1
 DEBUG [b2a3647b]   info No lockfile found.
 DEBUG [b2a3647b]   [1/4] Resolving packages...
 DEBUG [b2a3647b]   [2/4] Fetching packages...
 DEBUG [b2a3647b]   [3/4] Linking dependencies...
 DEBUG [b2a3647b]   [4/4] Building fresh packages...
 DEBUG [b2a3647b]   success Saved lockfile.
 DEBUG [b2a3647b]   Done in 0.15s.
  INFO [b2a3647b] Finished in 0.592 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [d8f59b17] Running if test ! -d /home/dev/apps/livelyteams/releases/20200918213106; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/releases/20200918213106'" 1>&2; false; fi as dev@livelyteams.com
 DEBUG [d8f59b17] Command: if test ! -d /home/dev/apps/livelyteams/releases/20200918213106; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/releases/20200918213106'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [d8f59b17] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [cbdabd40] Running RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.6.5 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile as dev@livelyteams.com
 DEBUG [cbdabd40] Command: cd /home/dev/apps/livelyteams/releases/20200918213106 && ( export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin/:$PATH" NODE_ENVIRONMENT="production" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.6.5" RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.6.5 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
 DEBUG [cbdabd40]   rake aborted!
 DEBUG [cbdabd40]   ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
 DEBUG [cbdabd40]   /home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in `method_missing'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:24:in `key_exists?'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:10:in `find'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/rails.rb:37:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/releases/20200918213106/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
 DEBUG [cbdabd40]   
Caused by:
 DEBUG [cbdabd40]   OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: 
 DEBUG [cbdabd40]   /home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `final'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `_decrypt'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in `method_missing'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:24:in `key_exists?'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:10:in `find'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/rails.rb:37:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/releases/20200918213106/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/dev/apps/livelyteams/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
 DEBUG [cbdabd40]   Tasks: TOP => environment
 DEBUG [cbdabd40]   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being to destroy the current production server and create and new one. Now my project deploys via capistrano like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is complaining about your `config/master.key` file. First (back them up, just in case) `rm config/credentials.yml.enc` and `rm config/master.key` then try running `bundle exec rails credentials:edit`.

Comment: I've tried that several times. Is there something I'm missing about the master.key? I run rails credentials:edit, then I scp the master.key to the deployment server in the shared/config folder. Is there anything else that needs to be ran.

Comment: I tried it a second time just to be sure. I am using :amazon for active storage, but I've also tried switching that to :local to avoid any key issues.

Comment: What about running the credentials task it with the `--environment production` flag?

Comment: Thats only on rails 6. I'm on version 5.2.4.4, which I upgraded to this morning to see if that would fix the problem. I guess I will try upgrading to rails 6 next.

Comment: I've now updgraded to rails 6 and it did not fix the problem.